# Append Content to iframe jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the get the textarea content entered by user from one of my and form and print that content in iframe, following is the code:

```
$('.btn-options > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').on("click", function(e){
  $(".textField > textarea").each(function(){
    var textareaCon = $(this).html();
    $(this).next().append("<div class='notes-data'>" + textareaCon + "</div>");
  });
  var divElements = $(".sg-Tab-panel.is-open").html();
  var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
  var iframe = $('<iframe class="hidden" id="printer"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
  var printer = $('#printer');
  printer.contents().find('body').append(" + divElements + ");
  printer.get(0).contentWindow.print();
  printer.remove();

});
```

The content is not showing in the print preview, however when I cancel and come back to the page again its working but not when I click on the print link.

**EDIT** Following code is not sending data to iframe, but when I console, I see that data:

```
$(".textField > textarea").each(function(){
    var textareaCon = $(this).html();
    $(this).next().append("<div class='notes-data'>" + textareaCon + "</div>");
  });
```

Whats wrong here, please suggest

thanks

Comment: `.append(" + divElements + ")` will work, but not as you are expecting it to

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how it will work then, please suggest

Comment: `.append(divElements)`

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but it doesnt work..still not content showing..

Comment: Can you post the html before and after clicking the button? Also, if you don't have many iframes perhaps you can target the iframe without using .next()?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `$(this)` in a temporary variable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please look at the question again as I have issue with the next variable..